# How to uninstall pywin32 using Pycharm Community 2017

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, pywin32, distutils

It is necessary for me to uninstall the existing version of pywin32 that was installed for my python projects. When I used pycharm GUI for the uninstall `"AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'main'"` error was prompted, and suggesting me to uninstall using PIP (`pip uninstall pywin32`).

When PIP was used the below message was prompted.

```
Cannot uninstall 'pywin32'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

Any help guiding me for the uninstall will be highly appreciated.

regards
Chalinga

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you (or some infrastructure you use) installed pywin32 using "distutils", you need to manage (and in particular) uninstall it "using distutils" because pip cannot properly uninstall packages installed by "pure" distutils, because distutils doesn't record enough metadata for pip to do so.Unfortunately distutils doesn't include an uninstall command, so "uninstall using distutils" means manually removing the package.

You can try removing package manually from "site-packages" in your virtual environment.